# Using rules of inference, show If ∀x(Q(x)→(R(x)∧S(x))) and ∀x(P(x)∧Q(x)) are true, then ∀x(P(x)∧S(x)) is true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Premise:

- ∀x(Q(x)→(R(x)∧S(x)))
- ∀x(P(x)∧Q(x))

Then show ∀x(P(x)∧S(x))  is true. I have been messing with this problem for well over an hour and I cannot find the rules of inference to prove this. I also cannot find too many examples online.

Any help is desperately needed.

Thanks

Comment: Given $P \wedge Q$ as a premise, by $\wedge$-elimination we can conclude $Q$. Then apply $\rightarrow$-elimination...

Answer (score 4):

*Hint*

Use [UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) with 2nd premise to derive $Pa \land Qa$ and then use [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) to derive $Pa$ and $Qa$.

Using again UI with 1st premise and then [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens), derive $Ra \land Sa$.

Use Simplification again and then [Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction) to derive $Pa \land Sa$.

The conclusion follows by [Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy. How do you know what to look for? I felt like I was spinning in circles and just picking random directions to go in. I don't have a concrete plan to attack these problems. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Zevias - the strategy is : first remove quantifiers and then use propositional rules.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been messing with this problem for well over an hour and I cannot find the rules of inference to prove this.

There are not *that* many rules of inference that might apply.

The premises have Universal Quantifiers, and Conjunction and Conditional connectives.

The rules of inference to use are clearly: **Universal Elimination, Universal Introduction, Conjunction Elimination, Conjunction Introduction, and Conditional Elimination.**  Not in that order.

(You may know them by different names, but they should be recognisable. For example: you might know them as Universal Instantiation, Universal Generalisation, Simplification, Conjunction, and Modus Ponens, or something similar.)

Start from the conclusion and work back to the premises: You need to *introduce a universal quantifier*, so do that thing.$$\begin{array}{|l} \forall x~((Q(x)\to(R(x)\wedge S(x))\\\forall x~(P(x)\wedge Q(x)) \\\hline \quad\begin{array}{|l} [a]\\\hline \vdots\\ P(a) \wedge S(a)\end{array}\\ \forall x~(P(x)\wedge S(x))\hspace{10ex}\forall\mathrm I\end{array}$$ Now, how would you introduce that conjunction...?